# I am unable to connect MySQL extension on local server

Tags: mysql

```
{
  "connectionMethod": "Server and Port",
  "mysqlOptions": {
    "authProtocol": "xprotocol",
    "enableSsl": "Disabled"
  },
  "previewLimit": 50,
  "server": "localhost",
  "port": 33060,
  "usePassword": "Save as plaintext in settings",
  "driver": "MySQL",
  "name": "MySQL Local",
  "database": "new_app",
  "username": "root",
  "password": "m4g1c4ln3gr0",
  "connectionTimeout": 100
}
```

I tried to connect to the local server but this what it shows "connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3300"

I have changed the port number but all my attempts were futile,the problem still persists.Please everyone,help this little brother out.

Comment: MySQL usually runs on port 3306, not 33060 or 3300.

Comment: It still doesn't work,using 3306

Comment: Then I doubt MySQL is up and running. You can always check what port it is listening on, if at all,  via `netstat`.